# Open angular popover when I focus on input text

Tags: angularjs, html

I have this little piece of code in my html page

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" id="field_telefono" ng-model="vm.indirizzo.telefono" telefono required/>
    <span class="input-group-addon" role="button" uib-popover="{{'theFoodApp.indirizzo.informativa' | translate}}" data-popover-title="{{'theFoodApp.indirizzo.informativa-title' | translate}}" data-popover-placement="top" data-popover-append-to-body="true">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign white"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Is possibile open the uib-popover when I focus on the input text?

Answer (score 0):

```
popover-trigger="'focus'"
```

You could also use ng-focus and ng-blur directives to trigger a toggle variable that is passed to popover-is-open="".

Comment: It doesn't work. Can you have an example with jsfiddle?